# Can I make my iPhone app subscription based?

Tags: ios, app-store

I made an app and I would like to know if it is possible to have a monthly subscription attached to a user account inside the app.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? Hope it helps/gets you started :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into in app purchases. A user can buy this in app purchase that then gives access to content inside your app.

There are different types of in-app purchases, one off (consumable), pernament (non-consumable), and subscription. Auto-renewable subscriptions is what you would want.

**Intro to in-app purchases:**

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

**Working With Subscriptions:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

**Review guidelines:**

If you dont want in-app purchases, you have to be careful with other payment systems used in the app and I would therefore suggest you do use in-app purchases. Look at their review guidelines on payments:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

Answer (score 1):

You can use in app purchase to make a subscription based app.
There are 2 kind of subscriptions:

1. autorenewable
2. non-autorenewable

If what user is paying will enhance some application functionality you must use In App Purchase offered by Apple that means that Apple will take 30% of your income. If you try to change the purchase mechanism you app will be probably rejected.
Instead ff your app sell subscription to a gym (for instance) you can use the payment mechanism you prefer, but better ask to Apple.